Z-index stack not recognized inside position static element
I'm trying to set up z-index values to stack my elements but strangely the 2 elements inside the position: fixed parent does not listen to z-index values at all.
summary
The parent is:
position: fixed;
z-index: 800;

The first child is:
position: relative;
z-index: -1;

The second child is:
position:relative;
z-index: 2;

But somehow the children of the first child are on top of the children of the second child.
I've tried adding
.support-bubble .list-group-item *::before,
.support-bubble .list-group-item * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

to the first child and also added the
.support-bubble>div *,
.support-bubble>div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 400;
}

so I'm making sure all children of the first child has z-index: -1 and all children of the second child have z-index: 400.


.support-bubble {
  z-index: 800;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: default !important;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.support-bubble>div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.support-bubble .list-group {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s linear 0.35s, max-height 0s linear 0.35s;
}

.support-bubble:focus-within .list-group {
  transition: none;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.support-bubble .list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgba(var(--bs-danger-rgb), var(--bs-bg-opacity));
  background-color: rgba(var(--bs-light-rgb), var(--bs-bg-opacity));
  outline: 1px solid rgb(var(--bs-danger-rgb));
  transition: opacity 0s linear 0.35s, max-height 0s linear 0.35s;
}

.support-bubble .list-group-item::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgb(var(--bs-danger-rgb));
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.support-bubble .list-group-item:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.support-bubble:focus-within .list-group-item {
  opacity: 1;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn support-bubble">
  <ul class="list-group gap-3 gap-md-2 mb-3 mb-md-2">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="AI Whatsapp Assistant">
      <i class="fa-regular fa-robot"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Whatsapp Support">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-lg"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Live-chat Interface">
      <i class="fa-regular fa-comments"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__pulse animate__infinite">
    <i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-circle-info" style="--fa-primary-color: #38501f; --fa-secondary-color: #38501f;"></i>
  </div>
</button>




Those z-index issues can be quite challenging! Unfortunately I cannot see anything in your provided example as the external styles and icons wont load. I suggest to simplify the example (get rid of bootstrap and icons, use colored boxes). This will help to isolate and understand the cause of your issue.

@lupz While I agree mostly, Bootstrap might be the cause for it in the first place.

By setting opacity you are creating new stacking contexts.

I tried to solve this z-index problem between the first and the second in the codepen with css changes. I think z-index is working well. I guess you probably are confused X, Y and Z axis in the screen. Could you read this article first? z-index in MDN and z-index in Web Dev. If I misunderstood, then I apologize. Could you explain more details?
